# ssh worked first time but not afterwards on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openvpn

I started openvpn via `sudo openvpn --config myopenvpnfile.ovpn`. Then I started ssh via `ssh username@host -i ~/.ssh/myFolder`. I was asked to enter my password once, which I did. It all worked and then I quit ssh via `exit` and stopped openvpn. Now, whenever I do the same procedure I get a non-responsive terminal upon `ssh username@host -i ~/.ssh/myFolder`, the openvpn part works of course. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong/ what I am doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Without knowing more about the server you're connecting to, it will be difficult to give you a definitive answer. However, have you checked that the system you're SSHing into is accepting traffic from your IP? A lot of VPN providers will not always offer the same out-going IP range, and servers with IP-based firewall rules can ignore traffic as a result.

Comment: Please post the output of `ssh -v username@host -i ~/.ssh/myFolder`, just make sure to remove the real IP info.

Comment: thanks for your answers. Upon using ```ssh -v username@host -i ~/.ssh/myFolder``` it worked again, can you briefly explain why?